# Check directory size and changing the permission to read only

Tags: scripting

I need to write a script that will check directory size and change the permission to read only with changing the ownership to root if a threshold value exceed.

- I have multiple users who have their home directories at /sasdata2
- I want to check each folder of user at /sasdata2 and change the ownership to root and change the permission to read only it each folder exceeds 100gb...
- The script will be running periodically say once daily...

additionally email to be sent to the user and the admin when any changes happens. 
For some users limit will be higher like 200 gb or for one user i think it is 1 TB so it depends upon each user as a policy its 100 GB or all.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks to all for answering, however I have sorted out a solution as follows:

Took 3 files called 100gb.txt, 200gb.txt and 1tb.txt, added respective users to the files.
Then ran the script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `more /sasdata2/SAS-USERS/100gb.txt`
do
uses=$(du -s /sasdata2/SAS-USERS/$i | awk '{print $1}')
uses_mb=`expr $uses / 1024`

if [ $uses -ge 104857600 ]; then
chown root:root /sasdata2/SAS-USERS/$i
echo "Your disk space usage is now $uses_mb MB. You are denied to write data at your home directory" | mail -s "Disk Space Uses" "$i"@mail.com,user@mail.com

elif [ $uses -lt 104857600 ]; then
chown $i:$i /sasdata2/SAS-USERS/$i
fi
done
```

Repeated the lines for 200 gb and 1 tb calling the respective text files.

Comment: did you try anything ?

Comment: U&L is not a script writing service, show some attempts.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

LIMIT='102400'

DIR='/sasdata2'

MAILTO='user@mail.com'

SUBJECT="$DIR Disk Usage"

cd $DIR

USED=`df -m . | awk '{print $3}' | sed -ne 2p | cut -d"M" -f1`

if [ $USED -gt $LIMIT ]

     du -sh ${DIR}/* | $MAILX -s "$SUBJECT" "$MAILTO"

fi

Comment: @heemayl can you suggest me some site to write such sciprts?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to enforce quotas rather than disallowing the users to do their job.

Comment: @Tasbir you'd be hard-pressed to find a site where people will write you a complete shell script for free, just because. people are happy to help - especially here - but most will not do your work for you.

Comment: additionally if you're going to provide an attempt, please don't do so in comments where it's unreadable and hard to find. instead, [edit] your question to include the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called `quota`, in which you can specify limits of disk storage for users and/or groups.

I'd rather work with that

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-quota-ubuntu-debian/

than scripting something like

```
MB_USEd=$(du -shm /home/foo)
if [ $MB_USEd -ge 102400 ]; then
    chown root:root /home/foo
fi
```

which might **not** work as expected.

Comment: Quota cannot be implemented as application is using one same account to store and process the data in these folders.

Comment: change the app. to use one user account per user